# How to add MFA redirects from an Acegis Security LdapAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, multi-factor-authentication

My question:

How do you add an extra MFA check to a system that uses Acegis security (the forerunner to Spring Security) to authenticate against an LDAP server using a custom Authentication provider that inherits from  org.acegisecurity.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider to allow authentication against our LDAP server.

Background:

I'm fairly new to Spring/Acegis security.  I have an existing system that uses Acegis security to handle logins.  It uses an custom Authentication provider that inherits from  org.acegisecurity.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider to allow authentication against our LDAP server.

However, we've been asked to implement MFA.  We have an MFA provider, but it requires doing another redirect to the website.  The problem that I have is that the security of this code is handled entirely by a series of classes derived from Acegis security.  As a consequence, I don't [seem to] have ready access to the incoming HttpServletRequest from the login.

The main methods that seem to be the place to implement the MFA code are:

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
{
...
}
```

and

```
protected abstract void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException;
```

However, the difficulty here is that in order to perform the MFA, I need to redirect to a MFA website, and then receive a code back from that site via a HttpResponse - but there is no Http objects at these points in the code.

Consequently, it is not clear at this point, how I would go about doing the MFA checks which typically redirect the user's browser to the MFA site, and then based on the response make the determination as to whether the extra MFA check has succeeded.

Thanks heaps,

David.